# Couldn't build release version of iOS project with hosted mac agent Azure pipeline

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

Getting these two errors when I try to build the iOS project with hosted mac agent.

`lipo : error : unable to find utility "lipo", not a developer tool or in PATH [/Users/runner/runners/2.158.0/work/1/s/src/LOT/iOS/LOT.iOS.csproj]`

`MTOUCH : error MT5306: Failed to create the a fat library. Please review the build log. [/Users/runner/runners/2.158.0/work/1/s/src/LOT/iOS/LOT.iOS.csproj]`

Have selected the xcode version `10.2.1`

I changed this based on the solution given in this reference, 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31493/mtouchtask-error-mt5206-failed-to-create-the-a-fat-library-please-review-the-build-log-mt5206

Some other links suggest this could be due to the license and tried `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` Still it doesn't work. Any leads?

**Update:**
After selecting the xcode `11.1`, `lipo : error : unable to find utility "lipo", not a developer tool or in PATH [/Users/runner/runners/2.158.0/work/1/s/src/LOT/iOS/LOT.iOS.csproj]` error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command in a bash script task resolved my problem.

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Basically it selects the xcode version `10.3`.